# Hide Super Admin user group for other user grup in joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I need to hide super user for administrator user group in user management.They have the permission to create and edit user expect superuser. Is there any solution for that? Am using Joomla 3.1

Comment: I've checked and double checked:
In Joomla 3.1 Admin user cannot Edit or in any another way modify super admin accounts. Also Admin cannot grant super admin access for other users.
Why do you want to hide super admin accounts in users list?

Comment: yes thank god just now checked, it's just list superadmin details without edit permission.It's good.. thanks @di3sel

Comment: do you still want to hide super admins? I can post a solution for that if needed, but this will require some core hacks of Joomla files.

Comment: yes i need the solution.don't need to show superuser details to other user groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will need to open file **/administrator/components/com_users/views/users/tmpl/default.php**
and somewhere around line 130, after this code:

```
if ((!$loggeduser->authorise('core.admin')) && JAccess::check($item->id, 'core.admin'))
{
    $canEdit   = false;
    $canChange = false;
}
```

Insert the following code:

```
if (!$canEdit)
    continue;
```

And that's it!

Comment: Thanks @di3sel it's working well.. now super user details not showed to other user groups thanks a lot :)

Comment: I suggest to use template overrides, otherwise your changes will be overridden on the next update.